# Is __W64 necessary when porting from C to C#?

Tags: c#, c, porting

Does __W64 need to be put into C# when porting from C to C# ?

Comment: How are you porting? In general there is no need for this. You can mark a project for 64bit compilation if needed.

Comment: I'm essentially copying and pasting then correcting for anything that doesn't work in C#. So are you saying that when I compile I could just say take this code and allow it to work for 64 bit?

Comment: .NET will compile to the native platform - 32 or 64 bit when jitting the assemblies. I don't know what you are porting and how important it is for the process to be 64 bit, but this tends to be less of a problem in C#. If it _is_ important, set the project to 64 bit.

Comment: What is `__W64`, anyway? If that's some define for some C compiler, then how is it related to the C# compiler?

Comment: "I'm essentially copying and pasting then correcting for anything that doesn't work in C#." it doesn't sound like a solid porting strategy... :S

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you have any recommendations. As far as I understand it porting goes Copy Paste, Correct, and check. In the end I want to preserve what the code was doing but put have the options to use the robust .Net framework that C# provides. Any tips are always appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `__w64`, lowercase w, the MSDN page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s04b5w00%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).  It was designed to help diagnose problems when code is retargeted from 32-bit to 64-bit mode, diagnostics generated by the /Wp64 compile option.  It has been deprecated since VS2008.

There is no equivalent in C#, mostly because that's a language that can be jitted to 32-bit or 64-bit machine code on-the-fly.  So no, don't copy that.  But do pay attention to *how* you translate the code, the original programmer put up a warning sign for some reason.  Usually it involves converting a pointer to an int, not the kind of code that easily translates to C#.